# How to use Generating Functions to solve the problem: Number of bit strings of length four do not have two consecutive 1s

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, inclusion-exclusion

I read this [QA answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3358299/1059606) and has problems about how it is solved.

The above referenced post's problem is:
How many bit strings of length four do not have two consecutive 1s?

Since [generating function](https://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2018/conf/15-1%20Manne.pdf) is done by letting polynomial coefficients be corresponding sequence items. Then how to get the following formula?

> Let $x$ represent the atom '$0$' and $x^2$ represent the atom '$10$' and build all possible strings by concatenating one or more atoms and removing the rightmost '$0$'.
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \overbrace{\vphantom{\frac1x}\ \ \ \left[x^4\right]\ \ \ }^{\substack{\text{strings of}\\\text{length $4$}}}\overbrace{\ \quad\frac1x\ \quad}^{\substack{\text{remove the}\\\text{rightmost '$0$'}}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\overbrace{\vphantom{\frac1x}\left(x+x^2\right)^k}^\text{$k$ atoms}
> &=\left[x^4\right]\frac{1+x}{1-x-x^2}\\
> &=\left[x^4\right]\left(1+2x+3x^2+5x^3+8x^4+13x^5+\dots\right)\\[9pt]
> &=8
> \end{align}
> $$
> Note that the denominator of $1-x-x^2$ induces the recurrence $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ on the coefficients.

Comment: The "Let $x$ ..." sentence says you are stringing together strings consisting of $0$ (length $1$) and $10$ (length $2$) hence the $(x+x^2)$ term, but many of them so $(x+x^2)^k$ term if there are $k$ strings, and you do not care how many so $\sum_1^\infty (x+x^2)^k = \frac{x+x^2}{1-x-x^2}$ as a geometric series.  This will give you the number of finite strings of any length satisfying the conditions which end in $0$, but you do not need that final $0$ so drop it and shorten the string length by dividing by $x$.  You want those of length $4$ so look at the coefficient of $x^4$.

Comment: You could also have looked at the coefficient of $x^4$ in the expansion of $\frac1x (x+x^2)^3 + \frac1x (x+x^2)^4 + \frac1x (x+x^2)^5$ to get the same result, as you know the minimum and maximum numbers of strings consisting of $0$ and $10$ you need to get one with five bits (before you lop off the final $0$) - at least three and no more than five.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for your comments. With your clarification help, I found my original generating function reference link may not fit in this specific problem. Then I refer to [this about Generating Function for recurrence](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Combinatorics_and_Discrete_Mathematics/Combinatorics_(Morris)/02%3A_Enumeration/08%3A_Generating_Functions_and_Recursion/8.03%3A_Using_Generating_Functions_to_Solve_Recursively-Defined_Sequences).

Comment: I can solve the above problem by another generating function form: 
$$
a(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i\\
xa(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^{i+1}\\
x^2a(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^{i+2}\\
(1-x-x^2)a(x)=a_0+(a_1-a_0)x=1+x\\
a(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x-x^2}
$$
the form is same as the above one. But how does these two be same? What does the above $x$,$x^2$ mean? Since $x^2=x*x$, does "0" and "01" also has this relation? And what does the ending "removing the rightmost '0'" mean?

Comment: Dealing with *And what does the ending "removing the rightmost '0'" mean?*, consider all the strings with 5 bits made up of $0$ and $10$.  They are $0-0-0-0-0$, $0-0-0-10$, $0-0-10-0$, $0-10-0-0$, $10-0-0-0$, $0-10-10$, $10-0-10$, and $10-10-0$.  They all end with a $0$ which can be lopped off to give $0000$, $0001$, $00010$, $0100$, $1000$, $0101$,  $1001$, and $1010$ respectively, which are the $8$ strings answering this question.

Comment: Using $0$ and $01$ instead of $0$ and $10$ would also work in the same way, except that you would need to lop off the $0$ at the start instead of the end.

Comment: Your generating function manipulation seems to be saying you are finding a generating function for the recurrence $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$ starting with $a_0=1$ and $a_1=2$.  That is a different approach but can be justified here.  It shows why you are getting Fibonacci numbers (offset).

Comment: 1. Yes. It seems these two generating functions are different. Since in my above equations which is based on the original answer link "Recurrence" part referenced in the question, I let $a_0=1$ and $a_1=2$ which corresponds to "0" and "1". Then $a_2=3$ corresponds to "10","01","00". Then could you say in detail how the above $x+x^2$ deals with length 3 maybe and $(x+x^2)^2$ deals with length 6 maybe? And why does $x$ and $x^2$ both has coefficient "1" when length 1 and length 2 have more than 1 related strings? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: 2. After expanding $\frac{1+x}{1-x-x^2}$, it is $1+2x+\ldots+8x^4$ which doesn't multiple $\frac{1}{x}$, so why does the answer emphasize that $\frac{1}{x}$ corresponds to "removing the rightmost '0'"?

Comment: On 1.  $x+x^2$ stands for a one bit string $($here $0)$ or a two bit string $($here $10)$.  $(x+x^2)$ means $k$ of these choices strung together.  You would need $k=2$ or $k=3$ to cover the ways of getting a three bit string (as you are going to lop off a $0$).  Note the coefficient of $x^3$ in $(x+x^2)^2+(x+x^2)^3$ is $3$

Comment: On 2. it is $\sum_1^\infty (x+x^2)^k = \frac{x+x^2}{1-x-x^2}$ which is multiplied by $\frac1x$.

Comment: Thanks for all the above patient comments. I understand all now. Begin with $(x+x^2)*\frac{1}{x}$, it will have $1$ and $\varnothing$, then $(x+x^2)^2*\frac{1}{x}$, it will have $01,0,10,101$. The rest is similar. Then the above generating function becomes beginning from $1,\varnothing$, with each step appending $0$ or $01$ which corresponds to one correct recurrence form $a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. so the $a_0$ corresponds to $\varnothing$, and since $0$ can be got from the step of $0$, so we only needs to care about $1$ with $a_1$ in the $x+x^2*\frac{1}{x}$